# For what programmatic reason do IoT-programmed devices always require cloud/server access?

Tags: server, routes, embedded, cloud, iot

I live in an area where net access is mobile or nothing. While I can occasionally get access by tethering a mobile to that network, it isn't often connected, and when it isn't connected, no local device will function on its own, no matter which protocol it uses. Why isn't there any kind of server/cloud resiliency built in where devices can communicate in a peer fashion like Apple's Bonjour (Rendezvous? I can't remember)? If I have an Echo device, I should be able to switch it on through an Alexa interface. I'm OK without speech processing which requires interpretation of commands through an AWS or Google or Apple or whatever cloud, but being able to locally control a switch seems as though the interface could be smart enough to route locally. I guess I may have just answered my question. It seems as though routes could be internally stored so as to not to definitely require a server. Can you imagine shipping a colony to Mars and all the IoT devices stop working? If you ask me, they should not require a branch variation or special programming in order to function.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming (and a "rant in disguise"). https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 1):

From the experience of having sat down and built a few, there are a some key reasons why viable IoT gadget products for the general market typically end up having to have a cloud-mediated mode, no matter what was envisioned when the design effort originally commenced:

- General consumers (at least think) they want the option to control things when outside the home
- Often even at home, a mobile phone may be on the mobile network not wifi, meaning that even if the user is physically inside their home, in network terms, they are not.
- Firmware updates, dynamic content, etc are easier when they don't have to be relayed through a mobile phone or PC, especially a mobile that might sometimes have to jump networks partway through the process.

Ironically, having once set out to build an IoT product that could work entirely offline, the further the project progressed, the more and more difficulties that approach presented for *general users*, and the more the cloud path that was added as an option, started to look preferable in terms of how things should work all the time so that it could become the exclusive focus of development efforts.

My conclusion is that it's very hard to build an offline IoT gadget.  Not only the developer, but also the *users* and marketing people need to understand and accept what sorts of difficulties and limitations that can mean.

So where does it happen?  In the situations where the "users" *are* the "developers" - eg. **open source**.   If you look around a bit, you'll find plenty of gadgets either built form scratch, or more commonly reverse engineered so they can run a custom firmware.  Want a local RESTful API?  Done!   Want could relay via MQTT over SSL to *your own* broker?  Done!

When you control the code, you control the mode.

But with products for the general market, most customers want things to work, not a lengthy technical explanation of why the details of their network setup mean they cannot.